# nullreferenceexception was unhandled c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am doing an insertion operation, But every time I am getting one error in line:

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
```

Saying,

> Nullreferenceexception Was Unhandled.

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace employeDB1
{
public partial class Insert : Form
{
    public Insert()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DatabaseConnection objConnect;
    int inc = 0;
    int MaxRows;
    DataSet ds;
    private void Insert_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
            row[1] = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            row[2] = textBox2.Text;
            row[3] = textBox3.Text;
            row[4] = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);
            try
            {
            objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);
            MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
            inc = MaxRows - 1;
            MessageBox.Show("RECORD INSERTED");
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize `ds`? Where do you have a debbugger?

Comment: Best way to handle such a common exception is to use whatever debugger you have. Just look at the stack trace in the exception and put a breakpoint at the offending line, then look at the values of whatever variables you use.

Comment: Come on! Only five answers to such duplicated question?!

Comment: @KonradKokosa: Wow... `"such duplicated question"`... much answers ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to do the initialization.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

I don't see any place from where you are filling your dataset.

What I understand is, You are creating a Dataset in which a table has 4 columns and then send this dataset to another function. For that

```
// create a dataset
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

// create a datatable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// add the columns into this table
dt.Columns.Add("col1");
dt.Columns.Add("col2");
dt.Columns.Add("col3");
dt.Columns.Add("col4");

// add this table to dataset
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
```

Now you can use the dataset `ds` as you are using.

Comment: Thank u. This error has gone. but now on the same line I am getting "index out of range exception was unhandled" error. plz tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a DataSet in this line

```
DataSet ds;
```

but not set it to anything, so when you call

```
ds.Tables[0]
```

`ds` points to null, not an instance of `DataSet`.

Initialise your DataSet as follows

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
```

Comment: Thank u. This error has gone. but now on the same line I am getting "index out of range exception was unhandled" error. plz tell me what to do?

Comment: You haven't added a table, so when you call `ds.Tables[0]` you are getting `null` not a `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an instance of DataSet

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); must exist in your code before any use of ds.

Comment: Please put some effort in to your answers, do you really expect this to help the OP who is clearly struggling with the basics

Comment: Thank u. This error has gone. but now on the same line I am getting "index out of range exception was unhandled" error. plz tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is null as it hasn't been populated with anything.

Look at the MSDN example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

From the above example:

```
 // Fill the DataSet.
 DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Suppliers");
 adapter.Fill(dataSet);
```

Comment: Thank u. This error has gone. but now on the same line I am getting "index out of range exception was unhandled" error. plz tell me what to do?